# What is this "?" in javascript what is and what does this code do

Tags: javascript

var name = "";
console.log( name ? "The name is " + name : "The name has not been informed" );

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Answer (score 0):

The conditional (ternary) operator
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator